# Trying to implement a speech to text, don't know what is wrong

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

New to Android development, trying to implement a speech to text that will print the words on the screen in real time but getting the below error. Can't seem to understand where the problem is. Is it because I am calling the **startRecording()** and **stopRecording()** from the togglebutton events or is is it something else entirely.

> com.example.android.moviebud E/SpeechRecognizer: not connected to the recognition service

```
package com.example.android.moviebud;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecognitionListener {
    ToggleButton recBtn;
    SpeechRecognizer recognizer;
    Intent recognitionIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        recognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
        recognizer.setRecognitionListener(this);
        recognitionIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recBtn = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.recBtn);
        recBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    recognizer.startListening(recognitionIntent);
                } else {
                    recognizer.stopListening();
                    recognizer.destroy();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle bundle) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "READY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Speech recognition started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRmsChanged(float v) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] bytes) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int i) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle bundle) {
        TextView v = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speech);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        for (String s : bundle.getStringArrayList(recognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION)) {
            sb.append(s);
        }
        v.setText(sb.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override**strong text**
    public void onEvent(int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it is working, I have done it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        checkPermission();

        final EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);

        final SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);


        final Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE,
                Locale.getDefault());


        mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRmsChanged(float v) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onBufferReceived(byte[] bytes) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onEndOfSpeech() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int i) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResults(Bundle bundle) {
                //getting all the matches
                ArrayList<String> matches = bundle
                        .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);

                //displaying the first match
                if (matches != null)
                    editText.setText(matches.get(0));
            }

            @Override
            public void onPartialResults(Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onEvent(int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        mSpeechRecognizer.stopListening();
                        editText.setHint("You will see input here");
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
                        editText.setText("");
                        editText.setHint("Listening...");
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }


    private void checkPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (!(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                        Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Fore more details you can visit my blog post - **[Android Speech To Text Tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/)**.